# Changing yum source through Gnome GUI

Tags: software-installation, yum, repository, gui, source

This might be a silly question, but it puzzles me. I am using Rocky linux version 9.2. I wonder if there is a way to change the yum install source through gnome gui? that is, without using command line, just the mouse. I know how to do similar setting in Ubuntu. But for Rocky, i cant find the place. i googled it, but it seems to me that every tutorial on changing yum source is achieved through command line.

Comment: Do you mean Gnome GUI?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i mean, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no (popular) app to manage `yum` repositories. The options you have are from command line. For example you can use:

```
yum-config-manager --enable repository
```

to enable particular repo. Similar is to disable it. To add new repo you should add the repo file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and then enable it with above command. To list repos you can use command:

```
yum repolist
```